# Использование сессии в NodeJS в чистом виде

Tags: node.js, сессия

Господа, прошу подсказать

При изучении NodeJS не нашел модуля, который бы позволял использовать сессии в простом виде аналогично языку PHP. Имею ввиду, что самому многое приходиться дописывать. Те же идентификаторы.. Есть ли модуль какой? Что бы велосипед не изобретать?

p.s. Хочется объявить сессию на любой странице, задать переменные, и с другой странице при объявленной сессии считать переменные, но если смотреть на ВСЕ возможные примеры, в т.ч. с этого форума, у кого куки, у кого запись в MySQL, чистого примера с сессией нет.

Comment: Дело в том, что сессии давно уже стали антипаттерном из-за своей плохой масштабируемости. Проще отказаться от них совсем, чем решать проблемы с ними - потому и информации о них довольно мало.

Comment: Вообще же - вот, держите: https://github.com/expressjs/session